# EOF after reading a file?

Tags: python, file, readlines

i wrote a code that is pretty simple, but i cant understand one thing.
Code looks like that

```
name = open("test.txt")

def CountLines(name):
    return len(name.readlines())

def CountChars(name):
    return len(name.read())


print(CountLines(name))
print(CountChars(name))
```

And now let's say the "test.txt" contains 4 lines of text (line1, line2, line3, line4). After running this code i would get the output:

```
4
0
```

First one is ok, but why the second is 0? Because earlier function set to EOF? And if so, why it doesn't read the file from beginning? Is there a way to reload the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the second is `0` because you've already read the whole file, so there's nothing left to   read in `CountChars`.

You need to put `name.seek(0)` in there to get back to the start of the file before you call `CountChars`.  Check out the [file object documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects).